# MVC Route Giving a forbidden error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with an `MVC` app and the strangest thing happened, I was able to navigate to a a Route called "/Reports" that would allow me to go to "/Reports/Index" but now I get this 403.14- Forbidden Error. The strange thing is that I can navigate to /Reports/Index and that works just fine, but all of my links are now broken because I cannot navigate to "/Reports" I also can Navigate to "/Companies" and "/Quotes" just so that you know. I didnt change anything in route config as it looks like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Quotes", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: Best guess is you have added a folder in the app named `Reports` (you will need to rename it so that it does not match a controller name)

Comment: I did, thank you. That was the issue.